# Compiling terminal mp3player for Android in C and Fmod: Functions gets undefined reference

Tags: android, c, terminal, mp3, fmod

All functions throws undefined reference error.

Here's my code:

```
/*

terminal mp3 player android

requirements:
c4droid terminal fmod

requires:
copy fmod api lowlevel lib armeabi-v7a libs to lib dir

compile:
gcc -I./fmod/api/lowlevel/inc -L./fmod/api/lowlevel/lib/ mp3player.c -o mp3player 

*/

#include <fmod.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static FMOD_SYSTEM * system;
static FMOD_SOUND * audioStream;

int main()
{   
// Create FMOD interface object
FMOD_System_Create(&system);
FMOD_System_SetDSPBufferSize(system, 1000, 2);
FMOD_Channel_SetFrequency(0, 44100);

// Initialise FMOD
FMOD_System_Init(system, 64, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, 0);

// Load Mp3
FMOD_System_CreateStream(system,  "/storage/emulated/0/playlist/starat16.mp3", FMOD_DEFAULT, 0, &audioStream);

// Play mp3
FMOD_System_PlaySound(system, audioStream, 0, 0, 0);

return 0;
}
```

fmod.jar would solve the problem. How to use it or alternatives with GCC on c4droid terminal? Or should I use C with libasound? Sdl mixer works fine but it plays only one MP3 at same time and traps terminal by window.

Answer (score 0):

I added -lfmod to end of compile command. Now it gives : fmod depends libstdc++. Install it.

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes, final code:

```
/*

terminal mp3 player android

requirements:
c4droid terminal fmod and install some dependencies

requires:
copy fmod api lowlevel lib armeabi-v7a libs to lib dir

compile:
gcc -I./fmod/api/lowlevel/inc -L./fmod/api/lowlevel/lib/ mp3player.c -o mp3player -lfmod

*/


#include <fmod.h>
#include <stdio.h>


static FMOD_SYSTEM * system;
static FMOD_SOUND * audioStream;
static FMOD_BOOL * isplaying;

int main()
{   
// Create FMOD interface object
FMOD_System_Create(&system);
FMOD_System_SetDSPBufferSize(system, 1000, 2);
FMOD_Channel_SetFrequency(0, 44100);

// Initialise FMOD
FMOD_System_Init(system, 64, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, 0);

// Load Mp3
FMOD_System_CreateStream(system,   "/storage/emulated/0/playlist/starat16.mp3", FMOD_DEFAULT, 0, 
&audioStream);

// Play mp3
FMOD_System_PlaySound(system, audioStream, 0, 0, 0);
isplaying=(FMOD_BOOL *)1;
while(FMOD_Channel_IsPlaying(0, isplaying))
{

}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no, just download and link libstdc++ headers for compiler

compile command:

gcc -I/storage/emulated/0/Download/fmodlowlatencymp3player/fmod/api/lowlevel/inc -I/system/inc/ -L/storage/emulated/0/Download/fmodlowlatencymp3player/fmod/api/lowlevel/lib/ -L/system/lib mp3player.c -o mp3player -lfmod -llog -lm -lstdc++

Answer (score 0):

all .so libs needs headers, download those to /system/inc and link those to gcc with -I directive .

Answer (score 0):

solved!

download and link these headers or dev packets dependencies for fmod :

liblog android
libm android
libstdc++ android

extra:
fmod source : compile it for android 7 and 8